# how to select multiple cells using offset variable but keeping what is in top 2 rows selected

Tags: range, selection, multiple-select

I want to multi select cell on a worksheet. I might start with selecting `a2:g22` but next time I want to select `a2:g2` and offset the remaining rows by 20 so they will become `a23:g23`. The offset will have a variable which will have 20 added to it each time the code runs.

```
NextRow = Range("ba2")
NextRow = NextRow + 20
Range("a2:g2,a3:g22").Offset(NextRow, 0).Select
```

If `nextrow = 0` then range `a2:g2` is selected and `a3:g22` is selected then I add 20 to `nextrow` and I want `a2:g2` to be selected and `a23:g42` selected.
What I get instead is `a22:g22` selected and `a23:g42` selected.

Answer (score 0):

After doing something else for a few hours I realized that offset will always work with the entire range whatever that might be. So I tried replacing the cell references in the range with a variable with only partial success. If I have a variable called `SelRow` and I put in it the cell references Will that work. So that code looked like this:

```
SelRow = "A23:G42"
Range("A2:G2",SelRow).Select
```

This didn't work because my selection was `A2:G42` so I changed it to this:

```
SelRow = "A2:G2,A23:G42"
Range(SelRow).Select
```

And that worked. So all I needed to do was to start with a reference number that was used to calculate 2 more variables called `StRow` and `EndRow`The reference number can and will be anything but for now I started with 23.

```
StRow=23
EndRow = StRow + 19
NowSel = "a2:G2,A" & StRow & ":G" & EndRow
Range(NowSel).Select
```

That worked. The result of `NowSel`in this case was `A2:G2,A23:G42`This can of course get quite long so my final code looks like this:

```
StRow = Worksheets("Cell List").Range("A1") 'Get the last row number used
StRow = StRow + 20 'Set the next start row to last row + 20
EndRow = StRow + 19  'Set the last row for selection to start row + 19
NowSel = "a2:c2,f2:g2,a" & StRow & ":c" & EndRow & ",f" & StRow & ":g" & EndRow
Range(NowSel).Select
```

And now the following cells are selected `A2:C2`and `F2:G2` and `A23:C42`and `F23:G42`

Now I can create charts just by changing a reference number.